# I am trying to count the DAYs used such as how many Mondays, Wednesdays etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want the cells that are counting the number of days to be formatted to count.  I currently am doing this manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below and enter as an array :

```
{=SUM(IF(LEFT($B$2:$B$20,3)=(LEFT(E1,3)),1,0))}
```

You can enter this in E2, then drag accross for the other days.

To enter as an array, put the formula into the formula bar then press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

OR

If the date column is formatted as a TRUE date format, 
use the below:

```
=SUM(IF(TEXT($B$2:$B$20,"dddd")=E1,1,0))
```

Again enter as an array formula

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work.  Are you sure the cell I should use this formula for is E1 ?

Comment: @Auru  
apologies, enter it into E2, with your day name in E1 etc.

Comment: This will not work if the dates are true dates formatted to show the day, as Excel will see them as numbers and it will not find the text you are looking for.

Comment: Would it work if your replaced the left function with: text(a1,"dddd") and linked to the actual cell of day name for the match ?

Comment: Just an FYI Since TRUE/FALSE resolves to 1/0 respectively, if you add the `--` to the front you do not need the `IF` inside the formula: `=SUM(--(TEXT($B$2:$B$21,"dddd")=E1))` entered as an array.  It just saves some typing.  SUMPRODUCT, as I used it just removes the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: thanks, learning the full use of SUMPRODUCT is something i have been working on, in terms of power usage is SUMPRODUCT more efficient than an array ?

Comment: about the same in efficiency as they work very similar.  There are pro and cons to each.  SUMPRODUCT is easier for many users as it does not require CSE, but SUM works better in some cases, depending on data and format.

Answer (score 1):

Use this that takes your dates and returns the full name of the day to be check against the titles:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT($B$2:$B$21,"dddd")=E1))
```

Blank cells will be counted on `Saturday` because a blank cell = `0` and `0` is `Saturday, January 0, 1900` to Excel.  To skip blanks use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$21<>"")*(TEXT($B$2:$B$21,"dddd")=E1))
```

[image]

Comment: Scott - this worked for me for Sunday thru Friday but Saturday shows "1" when it should show "0".  I cannot explain why.

Comment: You are including a blank cell in your reference.  A blank cell is 0 or `Saturday, January 0, 1900` @Auru

Comment: @Auru see edit to skip blank cells.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$21<>"")*(TEXT($B$2:$B$21,"dddd")=E1))     This WORKS !!!!     Thank you sooooo much.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the `WEEKDAY()` function in conjunction with `SUMPRODUCT()`. To count Sundays use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(WEEKDAY(A2:A20)=1)
```

Change the comparison to `=2` to count Mondays, 3 for Tuesdays, 4 for Wednesdays, 5 for Thursdays, 6 for Fridays and 7 for Saturdays.

This does not depend on how the dates are formatted, nor whether there are times stored with the date.